# CrudRepository Find by Custom join field filter

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have below entity

1. RequestObj
2. AdditionalReqObj.

Both entities are linked with `REQ_ID` column in table (`reqId` field). I am using `Spring data CrudRepository interface` for repository.

Now I want to `findAll RequestObj entity` by `REQUEST.REQ_STATUS` which is open **&** linked Additional request should also be filter by `ADDL_REQUEST.ADD_REQ_STATUS`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REQUEST")
public class RequestObj implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "REQ_ID")
    private long reqId;

    @Column(name = "REQ_NM")
    private String reqUserNm;

    @Column(name = "REQ_EMAIL")
    private String reqUserEmail;

    @Column(name = "REQ_ID")
    private String reqComments;

    @Column(name = "REQ_STATUS")
    private String reqStatus;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "request", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AdditionalReqObj> requestDtls;

    ---getter setter----
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDL_REQUEST")
public class AdditionalReqObj implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "AdD_REQ_ID")
    private long addReqId;

    @Column(name = "ROLE_NM")
    private String add_req_comment;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "REQ_ID")
    private RequestObj request;

    @Column(name = "ADD_REQ_STATUS")
    private String addReqStatus;

    ---getter setter----
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to fire a Native Query on your method. You can do it like this,

```
@Query(value = "SELECT R.* FROM REQUEST R INNER JOIN ADDL_REQUEST AR ON R.REQ_ID = AR.REQ_ID WHERE R.REQ_STATUS = :PARAM1 and AR.ADD_REQ_STATUS = :PARAM2 ", nativeQuery = true)
List<ReqObj> findAllByAddressId(Object PARAAM1, Object PARAM2);
```